# Auto authentication using Active Directory domain credentials asp.net

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

I'm trying to implement auto authentication in an asp portal which will be used in an intranet only. 
I want to allow only specific users to use that and want to authenticate them using their NT logins of Active Directory.
Using the following code to get the user id but it is gives null.

```
String sUser = Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"].ToLower();
```

Help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can access the LOGON_USER variable you must make sure the user is in fact logged in - that variable is not present when using anonymous auth.

In your web.config change the auth mode to

`<authentication mode="Forms" />`

Windows is also a valid alternative for Forms if you wish to use it.

Have a look [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306359) for more info

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. I've written windows in the web.config but it says Err, Connection Refused when I try to run the web app.

Comment: Thats normally more a DB error, are you perchance trying to use windows auth to connect to a SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, trying SQL server deployed on a local machine which is on company's domain. I've checked the credentials again, the problem persists.

Comment: I think you are having two different issues here. One is AD Authentication (the original question) and another is Connection to the DB. I think for a connection to the DB issue you should ask a second question - so if other people have the same issue they can find it easier.

Comment: Found out that SQL server browser service was automatically stopped. Turned it on and everything works like a charm. Thanks mate.